# JBox2D cannot create world, params don't exist for type Vec2 & Boolean

Tags: java, jbox2d

Following several jBox2D tutorials (example 1: http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/jbox2d-tutorial.html) and downloaded the source code from Git (https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d) - using the main library folder.

When creating a new world; following error:

[image: Error]

Cannot find a constructor that comes with Vec and Boolean. Instead result is: Vec2 and org.jbox2d.pooling.IWorldPool type which seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look into the source:

https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/World.java 
you can see that there is no constructor for Vec2 and boolean.
Available constructors are:

1. public World(Vec2 gravity)
2. public World(Vec2 gravity, IWorldPool pool)
3. public World(Vec2 gravity, IWorldPool pool, BroadPhaseStrategy strategy)
4. public World(Vec2 gravity, IWorldPool pool, BroadPhase broadPhase)

that means that you have to rework your code. Maybe the tutorial bases on an older version (tutorial was made 13 December 2011), I have experienced such issues with libgdx someday after an update.